# How to include a CSS file with wp_enqueue_style() on a theme without wp_head()

Tags: css, wordpress

I want to include custom CSS file in WordPress using  `wp_enqueue_style()` function without using `<?php wp_head();?>` or `do action('wp_head');` in 
 the `header.php` file.  I tried to find an answer on Google and Stack Overflow also but couldn't get the answer. How to resolve this issue?

**Here is my code in plugin file :**

```
add_action('wp_head', 'load_style');
function load_style() 
{
   wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) .'css/styles.css', array(), '1.1', 'all' );
}
```

I placed this code in plugin PHP file and also tried on placing the code in `function.php`. I do not want to use `wp_head` in `header.php`.

Comment: I guess you have your reasons for that, but just remarking that if you don't use `wp_head` many plugins may not work properly. Maybe you should add the motives you want to do this, it can help to get better answers...

Answer (score 0):

Use below code,

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_style');

function load_style() {

wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) .'css/styles.css', array(), '1.1', 'all' );

}
```

Comment: i tried with 'wp_enqueue_scripts' also it not works.

Comment: any another idea ??

Comment: try add_action('init', 'load_style');

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'load_style');

function load_style() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) .'css/styles.css', array(), '1.1', 'all' );

}
```

Comment: i do not want to use<?php wp_head(); ?> inside head tag. I already tried this method it works. But wants to use without this.

Comment: are you using `wp_footer`?

Comment: yeah it now works. Thanks for the help Mr. George.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Easily you can just add style in your `functions.php` file, as before:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) .'css/styles.css', array(), '1.1', 'all' );
```

Or:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'load_style');
function load_style() 
{
   wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) .'css/styles.css', array(), '1.1', 'all' );
}
```

And then, create a new action in your `functions.php` file to print enqueued styles:

```
add_action( 'just_print_styles', 'wp_print_styles' );
```

Finally, use your action in your theme (like header instead of wp_head):

```
<?php do_action('just_print_styles'); ?>
```